# Getting "Index was outside the bounds of the array." while calling EnvDTE80.ErrorItems.item()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

I was trying to get all the error in the Visual Studio 2015 Error List window but I am getting an index out of bound exception while trying to access the ErrorItem through errors.Item(i) call. Am I missing any casting ?

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2 =  ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as DTE2);
ErrorItems errors = dte2.ToolWindows.ErrorList.ErrorItems;
for (int i = 0; i < errors.Count; i++)
{
    ErrorItem item = errors.Item(i);
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged? What happens if you do `i < errors.Count - 1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ErrorItems.Item` method seems to need an absolute index, starting from 1, so change your loop to:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= errors.Count; i++)
```

Then it should work.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Well the `.Count()` Methods of all Lists or Arrays start at 1, while a Index in the IT world always will start at 0. So at the very end, your count will reach a number that won't be in your index.

So try the suggestion of BviLLe_Kid and subtract 1.

**EDIT**

Okay forget that. I think that was a brainlag. But I think deleting this answer won't be necessary since I can tell that BviLLe_Kid suggestion is wrong.

SCIENCE

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> tmpList = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("List Item No" + i);
            tmpList.Add("Item " + i);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("_____________");
        Debug.WriteLine("List Count: " +tmpList.Count());
        Debug.WriteLine("_____________");
        for (int i = 0; i < tmpList.Count(); i++)
        {
                Debug.WriteLine(tmpList[i]);
        }
    }
```

Debug:

> List Item No0
>
> List Item No1
>
> List Item No2
>
> List Item No3
>
> List Item No4
>
> List Item No5
>
> List Item No6
>
> List Item No7
>
> List Item No8
>
> List Item No9
>
> ---
>
> List Count: 10
>
> ---
>
> Item 0
>
> Item 1
>
> Item 2
>
> Item 3
>
> Item 4
>
> Item 5
>
> Item 6
>
> Item 7
>
> Item 8
>
> Item 9

Comment: Doesn't the loop take care of that? Since it's `i < errors.Count`? With 15 errors the loop iterates up to `i = 14`.

Comment: @Sami ... Yup. Embarassing.